# Обслуживание статических файлов в Golang Fiber

Tags: golang, static

Что я делаю не так, если это код работает, только когда я указываю в url путь до index.html?
То есть так не работает: `http://localhost:3001/api`

Так работает: `http://localhost:3001/api/index.html` - документация отображается.
Документация это каталог doc c субкаталогами css, img, vendor и т.д. + index.html, в котором прописан относительный путь к этим субкаталогам.

```
so := fiber.Static{
        Index: "index.html", 
        Compress: true,
        MaxAge: 1,
        CacheDuration:10 * time.Second,
    }
    
    directory := filepath.Join(t.Exe.Dir, "../doc")
    app.Static("/api", directory, so)
```

При этом аналогичный маршрут на корень

```
so = fiber.Static{
        Index: "index.html", 
        Compress: true,
        MaxAge: 1,
        CacheDuration:10 * time.Second,
    }
    directory = filepath.Join(t.Exe.Dir, "../assets")
    app.Static("/", directory, so)
```

работает нормально.

Comment: браузеры вроде по-умолчанию ссылаются на index.html когда на корень сайта ссылаешься. не?

Comment: index.html указан в самом web фреймворке. И браузеры тут ни при чем. Браузеры получают ответ сервера и им пофиг что там и где прописано. Они просто рендерят ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `app.Static("/api/", directory, so)`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]